# How can I make SonarQube display issues by severity using a widget per rule repository?

Tags: widget, customization, sonarqube

Instead of the one default widget that displays the all issues by severity, how is it possible to split the issues by rule repository?

For example, one widget will only display issues by findbugs and it will still display the varying severities.  Then there would be another widget, looking the same, but this time the issues are by Checkstyle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This requires to develop your own SonarQube plugin as there is no such widget available.